# Casting a datetime column as date 'yyyy-mm-dd' in SQLdf

Tags: date, date-formatting, sqldf

Running this query in SQLdf and when I go to view or filter based on date I'm noticing the date column is in datetime format instead of 'yyyy-mm-dd'.  I tried casting the column as a date with the correct format but didn't work.  is there a way to format it in the query or update that column in the data frame after?

```
BUS_SERV_PROMO_ROLL_FCST <- 
sqldf(
  "
  SELECT 
     D.DATE

    ,D.DATA_ROLLS_FORECAST
    ,VO.VOICE_ROLLS_FORECAST
    ,VI.VIDEO_ROLLS_FORECAST

    ,D.DATA_ROLLS_UPPER_FORECAST
    ,VO.VOICE_ROLLS_UPPER_FORECAST
    ,VI.VIDEO_ROLLS_UPPER_FORECAST

    ,D.DATA_ROLLS_LOWER_FORECAST
    ,VO.VOICE_ROLLS_LOWER_FORECAST
    ,VI.VIDEO_ROLLS_LOWER_FORECAST

    ,D.DATA_ROLLS_FORECAST_TREND
    ,VO.VOICE_ROLLS_FORECAST_TREND
    ,VI.VIDEO_ROLLS_FORECAST_TREND

    ,D.DATA_ROLLS_UPPER_FORECAST_TREND
    ,VO.VOICE_ROLLS_UPPER_FORECAST_TREND
    ,VI.VIDEO_ROLLS_UPPER_FORECAST_TREND

    ,D.DATA_ROLLS_LOWER_FORECAST_TREND
    ,VO.VOICE_ROLLS_LOWER_FORECAST_TREND
    ,VI.VIDEO_ROLLS_LOWER_FORECAST_TREND

  FROM
    dataforecast as D

  LEFT JOIN 
    voiceforecast as VO
      ON VO.DATE = D.DATE

  LEFT JOIN 
    videoforecast as VI
      ON VI.DATE = D.DATE

  "
  )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4Aa7.png)

Comment: Please include the original data from the `dataforecast` data frame.

Comment: All of the forecasts joined together are 'yyyy-mm-dd' format and whenever I do the final query that joins them they get converted to 'yyyy-mm-dd 19:00:00' (won't let me post a picture in the comments)  Also, when I go to add a date condition in the where clause WHERE D.DATE >= '2019-12-22' the data set returns null.

Comment: Welcome, Andrew! I have some recommendations that will help us answer your question:

1) Make the query that returns unexpected results as short and simple as you can (for instance, does the problem only occur with those two joins?).

2) Post the actual results of the query, as well as the expected/desired results.

3) You mention that you tried casting the column as a date, but that it didn't work. It would help to show what you tried, and what those results were.